# printing an image pdf or text pdf using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can we print an image or text PDF with out using acrobat. Is there any 3party dll which can be included in our vb.net code.

I have Tried with primopdf software, But little bit confused how to add in .net application.
Is there any solution to handle print pdf.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO

Public Class PDFPrinter

#Region " CONSTANTS "
    Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Integer = 2
#End Region

#Region " API "
    <DllImport("shell32")> _
    Public Shared Function ShellExecute(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                        ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                                        ByVal lpFile As String, _
                                        ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                                        ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                                        ByVal nShowCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
#End Region

#Region " PUBLIC MEMBERS "
    Public Function PrintPDF(ByVal FilePath As String) As Boolean
        If IO.File.Exists(FilePath) Then
            If ShellExecute(1, "Print", FilePath, "", _
            Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(FilePath), SW_SHOWNORMAL).ToInt32 <= 32 Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

[SOURCE](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?508684-Silently-Print-PDF-with-ShellExecute)

Comment: thanks for your support, But i have got 1 problem that, Height and width of pdf has been changed so that only half pdf is displaying. I will place my output page over here.                             Path: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_nzYHWVJJ7KWExDTHZVMWttdlE&usp=sharing

Comment: can you say what settings can made while printing pdf

Comment: That might depend on your printer setup or something, I've never seen this problem yet. I tried it for myself and it's working properly

Comment: ya thank you for your valuable feedback..i have changed my settings.but I have removed acrobat printer then in which freeware can i print those pages